# how to filter swagger to show "/api" only actions

Tags: swagger

My ASP.NET Core project  has mixed API features and MVC(Razor Pages) features. And Swagger by default documents all controllers.

How to config Swagger to show APIs only starting with "/API/"? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Look for SchemaFilter and OperationFilter in Swashbuckle config (AddSwaggerGen).